# Set value to input, than click div to submit form

Tags: php, jquery, post, click, submit

I am very new to php java script and html so sorry if this looks sloppy. But I have been reading online and managed to put together a live search feature from a sql db. It populates a div tag with overflow to scroll the search results, the search results are individual div tags. I want to be able to click on the div submit the form and carry the variable of an $rmaNumber to $_POST so i can use it.

Here is the live search function. When i click on the div it puts the rmaNumber into the rmaSearch input tag which is great but i was thinking if i used onclick="document.rmaSearchForm.submit()" on the div tag it would carry it over to the form action.

```
$(function(){
        $(".search").keyup(function(){
            var rmaSearch = $(this).val();
            var dataString ='search='+ rmaSearch;
            if(rmaSearch!=''){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "searchResults.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success:function(html){
                        $("#result").html(html).show();
                    }
                });
            }return false;
        });

        $(".show").live("click", function(e){
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
            var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
            $('#rmaSearch').val(decoded);

        });

        $(document).live("click", function(e){
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if(! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
                jQuery("#result").fadeOut();
            }
        });
        $('#rmaSearch').click(function(){
            $("#result").fadeIn();
        });


    });


    </script>
```

This is my html. That lays just below the jquery script above.

```
<body>
    <form id="rmaSearchForm" name="rmaSearchForm" method="post" action="viewResultsForm.php">
        <div class="searchDiv">
        <p>&nbsp; &nbsp; RMA Search<br /></p>

        <input type="text" class="search" id="rmaSearch" name="rmaSearch" placeholder="Enter RMA Number" autocomplete="off" />

        <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is the dynamic search searchResults.php found in the jquery script.

```
if(strlen($_POST['search'])>=1){
$q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['search']);


$sqlResults=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE rmaNumber LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY rmaNumber");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlResults)){

    $rmaNumber=$row['rmaNumber'];

    $b_rmaNumber='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';

    $f_rmaNumber=str_ireplace($q, $b_rmaNumber, $rmaNumber);

    ?>
    <div onclick="document.rmaSearchForm.submit()" class="show" align="left">
        RMA# <span class="name"><?php echo $f_rmaNumber; ?></span><br />
    </div>
    <?php

}
```

If anyone has a better way of doing this I am well open for advice. Like i said i just started learning PHP, jquery, html/css and mysql in the past 6 months so i know my code is not as good as it should be but im still learning. If more information is needed please ask more than willing to tell more if i have left something out.

Comment: FYI, `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. You should use `.on()` for event delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
$("#rmaSearchForm").on("click", ".show", function() {
    var name = $(this).find(".name").text();
    $("#rmaSearch").val(name);
    $("#rmaSearchForm").submit();
});
```

`.on()` with a selector argument performs event delegation to dynamically-added elements, like `.live()` used to. There's no need to call `.html()`, then create a new jQuery object from that, and then call `.text()` -- you can call `.text()` directly on the DOM element. Then just update the input field and submit the form.

You might also want to look into using [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), as that seems to be essentially what you're implementing here.

Comment: I was looking at the JQuery UI Autocomplete looks like gonna see if i can alter that to pull dynamically data from a sql. Also can I still submit the form by the onclick attribute? or should i go about doing this a diffrent way?

Comment: Autocomplete allows you to use AJAX to query the server for the values, and it can search a database. Autocomplete usually just fills in the input field, then the user uses the normal Submit button to send the form. There may be a way to have it do the submission immediately, I'm not sure.

Comment: Also the above code worked perfectly, Thank very much. Learned a lot from this.